# Span splits, how to avoid that?

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

Here is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/STG22/3/

I want that span would not split in two different rows (like third did in the example above). How can I do it?

---

CSS:

```
span
{
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 250px">
    <span>omg omg omg</span>
    <span>omg omg omg</span>
    <span>omg omg omg</span>
    <span>omg omg omg</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple CSS:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STG22/5/

Full CSS:

```
span
{
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: when I use this in my example, all badges go off the div

Comment: What do you mean by "badges"? Can't see anything wrong, sorry.

Comment: maybe it's possible doing it without white-space?

Comment: Yes, with pretty complicated JavaScript, but why??

Comment: it doesn't work in my example, I do the same thing... What can be wrong in my code?

Comment: Edit your question with the code that doesn't work for you, maybe even live link, and we'll see what might be wrong.

Comment: i use the same thing, but it just goes out of box

Comment: Does accepting the answer means you got it to work eventually?

Comment: yes, I didn't put space between spans, that's why it didn't work :) thanks for help

Comment: You mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/STG22/28/).. you could have posted such link in the beginning - anyhow it caused all the `<span>`s to become one single "word" thus no wrap at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the css property [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) to `nowrap`, this will suppress line breaks due to space limitations

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space:nowrap` or `display:inline-block` (without `width` set).

If you weren't aware: `width` doesn't affect inline elements like `<span>`.

Comment: when I use display:inline-block, it becomes very "fat", try in the example